# Ps1exewrapper: Adding product version, product information and hidding powershell console, how?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using [Keith Hill's PS1EXEWrapper](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/make-ps1exewrapper/) to convert my powershell scripts to EXE files and adding them an icon (Thanks Keith!). I want to make some modifications to this wrapper but I'm a complete noob in c#, so perhaps Keith can help me. I want to set product version and product information to the generated EXE and hide, if possible, the powershell console.

Thanks for your help

Best regards,

Salva

Answer (score 0):

Setting the version and description is easy enough using the Assembly*Attributes e.g. add this to the C# code string `$src` in that script just below the last `using` statement:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ConsoleApplication1")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ConsoleApplication1")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2013")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Hiding the console from within the application is a bit trickier.  You could try pinovking the ShowWindow(HWND hWnd, int nCmdShow) Win32 API passing it the handle of the current process's mainWindowHandle and a value of 0 for nCmdShow.

Comment: "add this to the C# code string"? What? While this is kinda what OP is looking for, you're kinda missing the important bit of *where* this actually goes.

Comment: Take a look at the link in the OP's question.  Or look directly at the associated script here:  https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5a8d2641e0963a97&sc=documents&uc=2&id=5A8D2641E0963A97%217251#cid=5A8D2641E0963A97&id=5A8D2641E0963A97%217521&sc=documents it is a bit long to replicate here.

Comment: Thanks Keith! It works! What do you think about adding a switch to show/hide PS console?

Comment: I will look into it.  The problem with this approach is that the window *might* appear briefly before the code executes to hide the window.

Comment: FYI I went ahead and updated the script to add these Assembly attributes.

Comment: Thanks again! Using PowerGUI I can create EXE files hidding the PS Console window and encrypting the script but I cannot set an icon nor set STA. Perhaps PowerGUI guys can help me how to implement console hidding. Thanks!